# How to style a group of elements under the same div tag independent of each other?

Tags: html, css

How can I style the numbers  in the following HTML code independently of each other?

```
<div class="info-down">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">24</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">07</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">15</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try to put them in span and then add class to span and edit css.

Comment: Or use nth-child() pseudoclass to select desired child .col-... of your .row element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have two options.  You could add styling attributes to each of the numbers by adding this `style="color:red"`, so that the line will look like this `<div class="col-xs-4" style="color:red">`.  This would turn the color of the text to red. Or you could make a .CSS document and style it by adding id's to each of the div elements like this, `id="firstLine"` and then putting this in the .CSS document, `#firstLine{color:red;}`. the `#` character is used for styling elements by id's and the `.` character is used to style the elements by class.  The .CSS document is the recommended method of styling as it keeps code split up and looking nice and tidy.

Answer (score 2):

You can add ids or another class to each the divs and style those independently.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

UPDATE with Demo

```css
  .col-xs-4:nth-child(1)
    {
    color:red;
    }
    .col-xs-4:nth-child(2)
    {
    color:green;
    }
    .col-xs-4:nth-child(3)
    {
    color:blue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="info-down">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">24</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">07</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">15</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```